# Components index generated by spring-context-indexer seems to do nothing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The `spring.components` file in not generated.

The problem is described in-depth in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22338.

As turns out, in Gradle 4.6+ (that includes Gradle 5.x - I have verified in Gradle 5.1.1 and 5.2), the correct declaration is `annotationProcessor 'org.springframework:spring-context-indexer:5.1.4.RELEASE'`.

---

More questions for the good folks from Spring Boot - should the `spring.components` file be created in `./BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF/spring.components`? That's where is shows up for me, but I would expect it in `./META-INF/spring.components`.

Also, how can I see that the file is indeed produced & used? Any flags to toggle? Any specific packages to turn verbose logging for? Any Actuator endpoint to look at?

Comment: The file is created in `/META-INF/spring.components` but due to repackaging by the spring boot plugin will end up in `/BOOT-INF/classes/META-INF/spring.components`.

Comment: Can you edit your description so that it only contains the actual question? You went from no file generated at all to file generated but not at the place you expect to how can you check it is working. That's three different questions in one thread.

Comment: Would you prefer for me ask multiple separate questions relating to the same issue? Sounds like spam to me. If I know where the file is, I know the indexing works, right? If I know how to verify, I know the index is being used, right? That in total means the feature is fully functional.